# Problems writing output to csv file

Tags: python, csv, math, store

I've been assigned a task to log student scores for a maths quiz

Below is my task:

The teacher wants to use the results from students taking these quizzes to log their performance. The system should store >the last three scores for each student.

Every time I run my code no data is added to the csv file, also the "state" text file remains at 0 so even if data is added the scores won't be updated and instead appended to the row

Below is my code:

```
import csv
import os

name = input("enter your name: ")
classroom_num = input("enter your classroom number: ")
score = 5
print ("%s, you scored %d/10 questions correctly"%(name,score)) 
status = open ("state.txt","w") #Every time program is run +1 is added, so that column 1-3 are updated
with open ("state.txt","r") as f:
    state = f.read()
    if os.stat("state.txt").st_size == 0:
        status.write ("0")

state_ints = [ int(x) for x in state.split() ] #converts into int
addone = 1
if state_ints == 3: #If program is run more than 3 times the value in text file reset to 0
    state_ints = 0
    status.write (state_ints)
with open("Classroom {}.csv".format(classroom_num),"a+") as f:
    rows = csv.reader(f)
    for row in rows:
        if row in rows in row[0] != (name) in row: #Checks if name exists in file (if so name isn't appended to column)
            state_ints.append(addone) #Adds one everytime program is run so that score can be replaced for row 1-3
            status.write (state_ints)
            name_row = (row [0])
            name_row.append(name)
            score_row = (row (state_ints))
            score_row.append(score)
        else:
            state_ints.append(addone)
            status.write (state_ints)
            score_row = (row [state_ints])
            score_row.append(score)
status.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

In line 7 of your code you open a file in writing mode:
`status = open ("state.txt","w")`
So the content of that file, if any exists, is erased.Therefore the reading operation in lines 8-9 won't find any thing to read:

```
with open ("state.txt","r") as f:
    state = f.read()
```

You can read your file, do your updates then upload your data back to the file again.

Answer (score 1):

You are resetting state_ints before you write to the file. Do this after you write to the file. Or you will always write 0 to the file.